# References on the LHC experiments

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, large-hadron-collider

I'm looking for a references / short book which discusses what is going on LHC collider - specific experiments, collision processes, analysis of data, how exactly the facility is operating (not professional level but for a high-energy Phd level). I would love to hear your recommendations.

Comment: You can read the proposals and technical design reports (which may go by different names) for all the bits, and you can read the papers. Eventually there will be papers on the performance of various subsystems.

Comment: I should mention that I perfer "one compendium" rather than catching papers. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Basic rule: no one has written a nice book about things that are still happening and evolving.